# Algorithm for pipe cutting optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I've bee presented with the problem of finding an algorithm to optimize the cutting of a length of pipe into smaller, different lengths.
For example, you have standard pipes of 10 meters and you need to cut the following pieces:
4 pieces of 0.7 meters
3 pieces of 2.1 meters
7 of 5 meters
etc.
The objective is to keep find the optimum order in wich to make the cuts in order to keep the waste to a minimum.

I have a solution, but I am not sure it is the best.
First, I make a stack (stack1) with all the lengths, ordered by size with the bigger values at the top.
And I define an empty auxiliar stack, stack2
The array pipe[n][m] stores the results. n is the pipe number and m are the lengths to be cut from that pipe.
Then I do the following procedure (this is pseudocode):

```
i=0
j=0
while(stack1 in not empty or stack2 is not empty)
    a=pop(stack1)
    if(a==null)
        push(stack2,stack1) ;push stack2 into stack1
        sort(stack1)
        i=i+1
        j=0
        a=pop(stack1)
    if(a fits in pipe[i])
        pipe[i][j++]=a   ;this just means that 'a' will be cut from this pipe
    else
        push(a,stack2)   ;if it doesnt fit, save it for later
```

To sum it up: It always attempts to cut the largest requested piece it can. When it can't it goes to the next item and so on. When it runs out of items to try, it begins with a new "virgin" standard lenght of pipe.

This seems to work but I wanted to know if it can be improved. Is there a way to know for sure what the best solution is?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the Knapsack Problem (an NP-hard problem in computer science).

Comment: If the above code works and you're looking  for ways to optimize it, your question might be better suited for [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried a variant in which, if the excedent is non zero, try to repeat the operation leaving out the second largest piece for later, if it still greater than zero leave out the third largest, etc. This gives a different distribution but always the exact same overall performance (except it takes longer to compute).

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the same as the [Bin Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and the algorithm that you've chosen is "sometimes known as the first-fit decreasing algorithm"<sup>1</sup>. That algorithm is designed for speed, but does not always result in an optimal solution.

<sup>1</sup> quoted from the [linked wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: Specifically, see the "Exact algorithm" section which references MTP.

Answer (score 2):

This is the cutting stock problem.  Your algorithm does not produce the optimal solution, as user3386109 noted.  It's also NP-hard, since bin packing can be reduced to cutting stock.

As an example of why your algorithm isn't optimal, suppose your pipes have length 100 and you need to cut four 34-length pipes and eight 33-length pipes.  The right thing to do is cut three pipes into two 33's and a 34.  However, your first-fit method will cut two pipes into two 34's, two pipes into three 33's, and one pipe into two 33's.

If there aren't very many useful ways to cut up a pipe (say, at most a few thousand), you can enumerate them all and you get an inequality knapsack problem that's usually not too hard to solve.  If there are rather more useful ways to cut up a pipe, there is a famous column generation method due to Gilmore and Gomory that is useful in practice.